# Core Data confusion in retrieving records

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm currently building a Core Data app and I've hit a snag.  I guess here's some context on the schema:

The app is to keep track of a therapist's session with her clients.  So the schema is organized thus: there's a table of clients, clients have sessions, sessions have activities, and activities have metrics.  In the app these metrics translate to simple counters, timers, and NSSliders.

The crux is that the client wants to be able to insert previously made activities into new sessions for new clients.  So, I've tried just doing a simple fetch request and then moved on to an NSFetchedResultsController.  I keep running into the issue that since Core Data is an object graph, I get a ton of activity entries with virtually the same data.  The only differentiating property would be whatever the session is (and if you want to go further back, the client itself).

I'm not sure if this is something I need to change in the schema itself, or if there's some kind of workaround I can do within Core Data.  I've already tried doing distinct fetch results with  the NSFetchedResultsController by using the result type NSDictionaryResultType.  It kind of accomplishes what I want but I only get the associated properties of the entity, and not any children entities associated with it (I need those metrics, you see).

Any help is appreciated, and I can post code if desired even though I don't really have a specific coding error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the problem. If you modeled things with the `Client`, `Session`, `Activity`, and `Metric` entities, each having a to-many relationship to the one to its right and to-one/to-many inverse relationship to the one to its left (in the order I listed the entities), there is nothing stopping you from adding a particular activity into another session (of another client), is it?

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: I have things modeled exactly that way, and I agree I don't think there should be anything stopping me. Maybe my question is "what's the best way of going about that"? NSFetchedResultsController gave me mixed results.

Comment: @jason328 Maybe you need to write code to get the exact Activity object that you want. You do that using an `NSFetchRequest` and `NSPredicate`, as described here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW1 Then, you can add that object to the Session object you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple NSFetchRequest and set the predicate for exactly what you are looking for. You can set the fetch limit if you are getting too many results but your question doesn't exactly sounds like a question IMO.

I believe what you are looking for is an NSPredicate to narrow your results down. Once you fetch a specific object you can assign any relation or attribute to that object easily with dot notation then save the context.